# angular trouble with http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller.js

```
var eclassApp = angular.module('eclassApp', []);

eclassApp.controller('StudentsListCtrl', ['$scope','$http', 
    function($scope, $http){

        $http.get('/static/js/students.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.students = data;
        });

        $scope.orderProp = 'last_name';

}]);
```

My html is the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="eclassApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->    
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/js/controller.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="StudentsListCtrl">
        <h3>Class B3</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                Search: <input type="text" ng-model="query">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <select ng-model="orderProp">
                    <option value="last_name">Alphabetical</option>
                    <option value="age">Youngest</option>
                    <option value="-age">Oldes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="student in students | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
                    <p>{{student.name}}</p>
                    <p>{{student.last_name}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

my json file gets accessed normally (from chrome's developer's console) but still I get the following errors.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
at Object.parse (native)
at pc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:14:208)
at Zb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:76:379)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:77:237
at s (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:7:302)
at Zc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:77:219)
at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:78:349)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:112:20
at l.$get.l.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:125:305)
at l.$get.l.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:122:398)
```

Am I missing a tokken that I can't see?

EDIT: I'm sorry..As a python developer I'm used in putting commas after last element in an array, something json arrays don't work well :). I had forgotten a comma on my json file. Removed it and works great

Comment: Try by initializing `$scope.students = {}` as you are making async call

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
eclassApp.controller('StudentsListCtrl', function($scope, $http){

        $http.get('static/js/students.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.students = data;
        });

        $scope.orderProp = 'last_name';

});
```